# Using back reference in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a php function that returns a Facebook post as text. However, I want all the #-hashtags to be clickable and to refer to http://www.facebook/hashtags/{the-hashtag}. I tried doing this with the following preg_replace, but apparently I'm doing something wrong:

```
$postMessage = preg_replace('/#[^(\s|\p{P})]*', '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/$1" title="$1"></a>', $postMessage);
```

This outputs links where expected, so the regex seems right, but the output looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/" title=""></a>
```

So I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the back reference, but I'm not entirely sure what.

(Side question, is the `global` parameter not necessary in preg_replace? I'm used to using it in JS.)

An example of `$postMessage`:

```
Android Wear testen doen we met de Sony #Smartwatch3. Binnenkort volgt een uitgebreide review op de website ;-)
```

Output should be:

```
Android Wear testen doen we met de Sony <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/smartwatch3" title="Smartwatch3">#Smartwatch3</a>. Binnenkort volgt een uitgebreide review op de website ;-)
```

Comment: use a different php delimiter, `'~(#[^\s]*\s)~` and you don't need to add `g` modifier.

Comment: It should work. What is the content of `$postMessage`?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE Please see my edit. Maybe it has to do with `#` that should be subtracted from the back referent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
#([^\p{P}\s]*)
```

`[^\p{P}\s]*` matches any character but not of punctuations or spaces , zero or more times.

**Replacement string:**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/$1" title="$1">#$1</a>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wY1mU0/2)

PHP code would be,

```
$re = "/#([^\\p{P}\\s]*)/m";
$str = "Android Wear testen doen we met de Sony #Smartwatch3. Binnenkort volgt een uitgebreide review op de website ;-)\n\n";
$subst = "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/$1\" title=\"$1\">#$1</a>";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Almost. I have to subtract `#` from the back reference. I.e. the actual output should be: `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/{MATCH-without-#}" title="{MATCH-without-#}">{MATCH}</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#([^\s\p{P}]*)\S+
```

Just group your regex correclty.Its working.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/39